# Java Gif read and write

Tags: java, gif, animated-gif

I just want to read gif and write it in file (then I'll add it to the BufferedImage with another images and create one commone image). But now I don't know why my gif become static after reading and writing.

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("Uzga.gif"));
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "gif", new File("1.gif"));
```

Comment: [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) is a single static image. It doesn't support animated images.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't create an animated gift just by using ImageIO.write, you need to create the gift file with the right format to support animation, take a look to:
http://openimaj.org/apidocs/org/openimaj/demos/sandbox/image/gif/GifSequenceWriter.html

The GifSequencerWriter class constructor takes as parameters in this order the stream for the file where all images will be stuck together (output file), the type of image RGB, the size block of each individual image inside the big file, and a boolean if true the animation is played in a loop. BufferedImage img can be the same you are defining. The big file will be all the individual images or photo frames and when played in sequence do the animation effect.

Some sample code:

```
System.out.println("Writing to file.");
ImageOutputStream stream = null;
BufferedImage img = BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("Uzga.gif"));;
try {
      stream = new FileImageOutputStream(outFile);
      GifSequenceWriter writer = new GifSequenceWriter(stream, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, BLOCK_SIZE, true);
      for (BufferedImage img: imgs) 
      {
        writer.writeToSequence(img);
      }
      writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Oh, but one more question, how I can make array of images from one gif?